# "Template missing error " in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am beginner in rails 
In `routes.rb` I have

```
root 'post#index'
resources :posts
```

When I click on "new post" for the empty title of the post,I get a error like

```
Missing template posts/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/supranimbus12/RoR/instagram_app/app/views" * "/home/supranimbus12/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.0/app/views"
```

My `posts/new.html.erb` file like

```
<h2>New Post</h2>

<hr>

<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <% f.label :description %>
    <% f.textarea :description %>
    <hr>
    <% f.submit %>


<% end %>
```

Comment: posts/new.html.erb file

Comment: @Dhinakaran please follow the given answer below as i have described your doubt in short, let me know for further guidance and feel free to accept/upvote answer (for me and future SO searcher).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- change routes as: -

```
root 'post#index'
resources :posts, except: [:index]
```

because you have already defined as root of index action

2- now for for new action

```
def new
@post =  Post.new
end
```

3- in you `app/view/posts/new.html.erb`

```
<h2>New Post</h2>
<hr>
    <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
        <% f.label :description %>
        <% f.textarea :description %>
        <hr>
        <% f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

3 - after hitting the submit button it will go to create action,

note: - because `form_for object` automatic hit to create action if `object` is new otherwise it will hit the `update` action that's why we generally use this form as partial to use it for edit and new action both

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  if @post.save
   flash[:notice] = "post saved successfully!"
   redirect_to @post
  else
   flash[:error] = @post.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
   render 'new'
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit!
end
```

to permit all data make a private method for strong parameter

```
post_params
```

and here `redirect_to @post` will go to `show` action if post saved in db,as it will make url like `post/:id` otherwise it will render to `new` template again. with error flash message.